# Website with login

Tags: php, html, wordpress, drupal, joomla

I want to create do the following things:
1. Create a new E-Commerce website
2. Update a already made website(superbrainacademy.com)

So the second thing, I have to include a log in provision so that some people which I authorize can get to see certain extra pages than others.

In e-commerce website I want everything like they can sign up themselves, I do not want to add each person manually, they log in with their email id and password and do shopping like something like flipkart.com. Well, payment gateway is out of scope for this question. What I need to know is how to start? In what language to make all this? Any guide on this?

**What I know and i have created:** I know programming in html and a little bit css. I make websites from downloading some good templates or just putting nice images at back and all. See my websites to have an idea(superbrainacademy.com or octindia.com)

I thought that maybe I could achieve this through joomla/drupal/wordpress. So I downloaded xampp and installed wordpress, drupal and joomla on it. The websites that open up look basic blogs to me (sorry but i am new to it) So I have no idea whether or not what I want can be accomplished by use of any of them. I also downloaded many many wordpress templates but they looked disgusting.

**So what I need:** A way to create a website with login id and password (signing in and signing up) but one has to be authorized by me as the users < 20 or so and the other needs to be done automatic as users > 100 or idk maybe greater. So how should i start.

Note: I do not prefer using automatic website making like weebly and all...

Comment: The site (superbrainacademy.com) sells education courses/products. So - what kind of e-commerce functionality do you require:

a) Is it a downloadable course/product?
b) Are the users subscription based?
c) Is it product that you send to people?

Comment: @iamrobert in superbrain i do not need e commerce but i need login for people who are my branches so they have access to a list of excel files and i also want to set up a different e-commerce website(selling technology stuff)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Joomla with VirtualMart. If you don't need all functionalities of joomla just disable those from back-end. If you need a pure e-commerce site you can use OpenCart (lightweight solution) or Magento which is a much more complex e-commerce solution.

**Update:**

The second thing couldn't be accomplished by using HTML only. wardha-Web's answer below (php login) seems to be a good choice since it's quite simple. Another sophisticated way would be to modify your existing site and put it behind to a php framework where you can define access role based authentication, but for this you need to have some php and object oriented programming skills

Comment: What about the other problem?

Comment: Moved comment to my post based on site policies.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a CMS.  If your willing to put some time into it you can learn to build your own template.  I haven't used wordpress but I have built templates for Joomla, it takes some time to learn probably just as much time it would take to do what you want to do from scratch.  Check out their guide to building a basic Joomla template.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

Comment: What about the other problem?

Comment: Joomla has all the built in requirements for user login and registration.  There are plenty of extensions you can use for eCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that, you just need an e-commerce cms, and its likes of .

My suggestion for you is to deploy a [**Magento**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) installation with a prebuilt template and demo just so you know where to start, and it gets easier for you to do stuff yourself, once you get a hang of it.

There are various of Magento/osCommerce template service providers out there some of them free maybe, some of them premium. Though I strongly bias my recommendation towards Magento than osCommerce, after myself having worked on both.

**Note:-** I am taking about opensource here, and mostly all of these cms installations tend to be quite similar.

**Update:-**

About integrating a login system inside your current website, you can use a script from [**HERE**](http://www.php-login.net/) as per your requirement and complexity.

Comment: What about the other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has inbuilt ACL:
http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

so that would enable you to set specific access for specific user groups eg branches

It would allow you to either:
a) let people register individually
b) you approve each registration
c) you set up each user individually

You could also combine Joomla with an eCommerce component.

I find mixing Joomla with Mijoshop (OpenCart for Joomla) a good solution.